# How can I create automatic paragraph breaks in a VBA textbox?

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, paragraph

I'm currently pulling text from a cell on a worksheet to a textbox on a userform. I don't even know if it's possible, but I ideally want to be able to put a symbol in the cell that separates lines and creates bullet points in the textbox.

For instance, make this information in a cell:

NOTE (SALE): SAID HE CAN ONLY GIVE THAT BIG AMOUNT ONCE A YEAR AND WANTS TO DO IT FOR THEM. JUST STARTED WORKING AGAIN SO PM IS BEST - NOTE (SALE): TRIED TO GIVE THROUGH THE MAIL, JUST BRING UP HIS CARD INFO (2/9/23)

Look like this in the textbox:

- NOTE (SALE): SAID HE CAN ONLY GIVE THAT BIG AMOUNT ONCE A YEAR AND WANTS TO DO IT FOR THEM. JUST STARTED WORKING AGAIN SO PM IS BEST
- NOTE (SALE): NOTE (SALE): TRIED TO GIVE THROUGH THE MAIL, JUST BRING UP HIS CARD INFO (2/9/23)

I also, if possible, want to be able to tab through the different bullet points. Is this even possible?

Comment: You won't be able to "tab through bullet points", but you can make it look kinda like that just using a normal bullet that you can copy/paste - here's one `•` - Where is your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking for the textbox to display output as a proper bulleted list (like it does in Markdown), I don't believe that's possible. However, a plain-text list is doable. Textboxes have a `Multiline` property as well as a `Scrollbars` property. You can set them manually in the Userform editor or do it with VBA during Userform Initialization:

```
TextBox.MultiLine = TRUE
TextBox.Scrollbars = fmScrollBarsVertical
```

For the list creation, if the input is *guaranteed* to match your example, a simple replacement will add a linebreak at every "-"

```
txt = ActiveCell.Text   'Pulling from the ActiveCell as an example
txt = Replace(txt, "-", vbNewLine & "-")
txt = "-" & txt         'Add the first "bullet"
```

However, you'll want to add more text parsing to get the correct output. As a start, you could use `InStr(txt,"-")` to determine if you should add the dash to the start.

Moving onto the Tab feature, the `KeyPress` event can be utilized (replace "TextBox1" with your TextBox's name):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    'Listen for the Tab key
    If KeyAscii = vbKeyTab Then

       'Move the cursor location to the next instance of "-"
       TextBox1.SelStart = InStr(TextBox1.SelStart + 1, TextBox1.Value, "-")
       
       'Suppress the Tab from creating spaces
       KeyAscii = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

In order for Tab to actually work, you'll have to enable its typical behavior in the Userform. Once again, this can be done manually via editor or with VBA `TextBox.TabBehavior = TRUE`.

Comment: The Replace function worked perfectly! Note that instead of replacing the "-", I replaced the spaces too: " - ". When I wasn't replacing the spaces, it was creating huge line breaks instead of just one. Thank you!!

Comment: The tab sub however is not working for me. I have inserted it and replaced the textbox names and turned on tabkeybehavior. However, when I press tab, it just highlights the other objects on my userform. Troubleshooting right now.

Comment: Try playing around with the other Control properties involving Tab. You could also add a `Debug.Print "Tab Keypress Detected"` in the KeyPress event conditional to make sure it's being properly captured.